Mediation package for R vs Hayes' PROCESS macro?
I am a beginner to mediation, and I am curious about the differences between the mediation package for R and the Hayes' PROCESS macro for R.
Do these software work with similar principles or would they lead to different results? Is there a main difference between the two?
I would like to use the mediation package because it provides a proportion mediated with confidence intervals, but I am wondering if there are any other differences between the two that should inform my decision.
